# Proof set of a sentence (error in textbook?)

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I'm reading the Chellas book on Modal Logic and in one place he defines the *proof set* of a sentence relative to a system $\Sigma$, denoted $|A|_\Sigma$ to be the set of a $\Sigma$-maximal sets of sentences containing $A$.  In other words

$$|A|_\Sigma = \{\max_\Sigma\Gamma: A\in \Gamma\}$$

However, elsewhere he defines a *canonical model for $\Sigma$* to be a model in which every world is $\Sigma$-maximal and for each $P_i$ (the set of worlds at which atomic sentence $\mathbb{P}_i$ is true) we have $P_i=|\mathbb{P}_i|_\Sigma$.

This last part makes little sense to me, though, because $P_i$ is supposed to be a set of worlds while $|\mathbb{P}_i|_\Sigma$ is supposed to be a set of sets of sentences.  I guess we could resolve this by taking worlds to themselves be sets of sentences, even though as far as I've read Chellas leaves the notion of a world un-analyzed.  Anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can think at a *possible world* as the set of atomic sentences : the set of atomic sentences *true* in it.

If you are more "accustomed" to approach propositional logic in term of *valuations*, you have to consider that each valuation $v$ partition the set of atomic sentences into two disjoint sets: the set $\{ \mathbb{P}_i : v(\mathbb{P}_i)= \text {TRUE} \}$ and the set $\{ \mathbb{P}_i : v(\mathbb{P}_i)= \text {FALSE} \}$.

But, by bivalence, we can simply assume the first one : we will call it "a *possible world*".

See page 4 :

> The picture is of a collection of possible worlds - including our own, the real world - at which sentences of the language are variously true and false. Our purpose is to model this, and we do so by means of an an infinite sequence of sets of possible worlds,
>
> $$P_0, P_1, P_2, \ldots$$
>
> The intuition behind this modeling is that, for each natural number $n$, the set $P_n$ collects just those possible worlds at which the corresponding atomic sentence $\mathbb{P}_n$ is true.

The formal definition of "$A$ is true at $\alpha$ in $\mathcal M$" is in page 5 :

- $$\vDash^{\mathcal M}_{\alpha} \mathbb{P}_n \ \text{ iff } \ \alpha \in P_n$$
- $$\vDash^{\mathcal M}_{\alpha} \top$$
- ...

Consider the second case : it can be "read" as $\top \notin \alpha$, for any $\alpha$.

---

*Maximality* is a property of sets of sentences [page 53] and the *proof set* 
of a sentence $A$ is the set of $Sigma$-maximal sets of sentences containing $A$.

See pages 60 :

> Thus in a canonical model for a system $\Sigma$, each world is a $\Sigma$-maximal set of sentences (and each such set is a world), and for each such world $\alpha$ and each natural number $n$,
>
> $$\alpha \in P_n \ \text{ iff } \ \mathbb{P}_n \in \alpha.$$

As you can see, in this case it is stated explicitly that a world **is** a set of sentences.

Comment: OK, follow-up question then.  Truth of $\mathbb{P}_i$ at $\alpha$ is defined as $\alpha\in P_i$.  This leaves open the possibility that, for instance, $\alpha = \{\}$ and $P_0=\{\alpha\}$ so that even though $\mathbb{P}_0$ is true at $\alpha$ we still have $\mathbb{P}_0\not\in \alpha$.  This seems to violate the intended reading of worlds as being the collection of sentences true at them.  In canonical models, though, this seems not to be a problem:  In this case, as you point out, atoms are true precisely in the worlds that have them.

Comment: Is that the point of canonical models, to finally make the concepts agree with the intuitive motivations in this way?  If so, why would we ever not use canonical models?  Why not just enforce that any model of a system has to be a canonical model?

Comment: @Addem --- I'm not sure to understand... $\alpha = \{ \}$ means that there are **no** atomic sentences true in that world; it like a valuation $v$ such that $v(p)= \text{ FALSE}$ for every $p$.

Comment: Well there are no sentences in $\alpha=\{\}$.  But the definition of truth was not taken to be membership in a world, right?  The definition of truth for an atomic sentence is $\vDash_\alpha^\mathcal{M} \mathbb{P}_i$ if and only if $\alpha \in P_i$.  That is to say, truth was not formally defined in terms of a sentence being in a world, but a world being in an atomic sentence's set.  So even where $\alpha=\{\}$ we could still take $P_0=\{\alpha\}$ and then by definition of truth we would have $\vDash_\alpha^\mathcal{M} \mathbb{P}_0$, right?

Comment: @Addem - I think not; from the above quotation, $P_n$ is the set of worlds where the corresponding atomic sentence $\mathbb P_n$ is true; if so, if $\alpha$ is an "empty" world, i.e. no atomic sentence is true in it, $\alpha \notin P_0$ because $P_0$ is the set of world where   $\mathbb P_0$ is true.

Comment: I see that this is the intention, for the worlds to only contain sentences true in them--but that doesn't seem to be a formal requirement until talking about canonical models, no?  The quotation taken from chapter 1 was where everything was informal to provide intuitions, but the formal definition in chapter 2 made no restrictions on what worlds could be in an atomic sentence's set $P_0$.  As far as I can tell, that only becomes necessary when dealing with canonical models.  But if my understanding is right, why would you ever use any other model?

Comment: Or maybe to explain my confusion another way:  If worlds really are the sets of sentences true in the world, then how is a canonical model different from any other model?  It seems to me the definition of a canonical model is basically the requirement that worlds contain all and only the sentences true in them.